# What core should every starting Town Center have?

Tags: skyward-collapse

For each faction, a town center allows placement of building/resource tiles in a two block radius, making for a 5x5 square of influence (with the town center in the middle). This leaves a total of 24 squares left to place improvements on, but that number quickly dwindles as you create more advanced tiles and get them destroyed by the opposing faction.

Stone appears to be a very valuable resource (it is used in most buildings, including Town Centers), I would consider making more than just one quarry if not for the space requirements.

Other than the obvious tiles such as pig farms, a butcher, barracks, woodcutter and the like...are there any tiles a starting Town Center (on each side) cannot go without? Also, when is the best time to create a new Town Center so that expansion may resume?

Comment: I've found stone to consistently be the limiting factor in my growth. More than one quarry seems to be a must.